# opencv link1104 error

Tags: opencv

i've created a new C++ project in Visual Studio 2008.  project settings have been changed.

When I compile the project, I receive the following fatal error:

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'cv200.lib'

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the project settings properly. 
1) Locate the file cv200.lib. you can find it in lib folder under the opencv folder.
2) goto project properties->linker->input->additional dependencies-> add the path to cv200.lib
like "C:\OpenCV2.1\lib\cv200.lib"

same way you should add
highgui200.lib and cxcore200.lib

Comment: @vivek did you change the settings as mentioned in this answer?